# for statement does not work as intended

Tags: python, for-loop

so the code is intended to increase the value of count every time it meet the requirement of the if statement and in the end it gives the count of how many times one particular item has appeared in the list, here is the code

```
x = ["fizz", "fizz", "fizz"]

def fizz_count(x):
    count = 0
    for fizz in x:
        return count+1
```

now i will only gets me 1 ,for i do aware that the for loop stopped at the very first "fizz"
how do i get it going ?(i tried print it return me three one, now that is a start cause if i am able to tell python to check how many one there is i will get the frequency of which the string "fizz" had appeared :)

thank you for anyone who take a look at this

Comment: `return` exits the function immediately.

Comment: Are you hoping to get back `1`? Or `(1, 2, 3)`? Or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are returning from the for loop on the very first iteration, that is why you get `count = 1`. You should increment the `count` in loop, and return it at the end of the function.

---

However, your for loop is not doing what you want it to do. It will not search for `fizz` in the list. The loop variable `fizz` will take each element in order from the list, and not just the element with value `fizz`.

If you want to count the total number of `fizz`, you need to add an `if` condition, to test the value. Or you can simply use a [*generator expression*](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/functional.html?highlight=sum#generator-expressions-and-list-comprehensions), with [`sum()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sum) function:

```
def fizz_count(x):
    return sum(1 for item in x if item == "fizz")
```

Or, even simpler, use [`list.count(item)`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sum) method:

```
def fizz_count(x):
    return x.count("fizz")
```

Comment: wow thanks for the such detailed answer, it is fair to say it is a bit out of my comprehension at least for now   would you be kind to write a example of achieving what you have said in for statement as it was required on the course i am doing right now

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that the `return` statement will exit out of the function, so you will only loop once, and always return `count + 1`, which is `0 + 1 = 1`.

You can fix this by not returning `count+1`, but rather by returning the total:

```
def fizz_count(x):
    count = 0
    for fizz in x:
        count = count+1
    return count
```

To get the number of times a particular item as appeared, you can use the `if` statement:

```
def fizz_count(x, item):
    count = 0
    for fizz in x:
        if fizz == item:
            count = count+1
    return count
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it too with a lambda:

```
x = ["fizz", "fizz", "fizz"]
fizz_count = lambda s: sum(1 for match in x if match is s)
print fizz_count("fizz")
# Output: 3
```

Comment: thank you for contributing but i would so much want some simpler expression as i am new to python and i am sure there must be a simpler way to do it